# Can one reference to abstract type member of generic parameter

Tags: scala

Consider:

```
class X {
   type My
}

class Z[Y <: X] {
   var bla : Y#My // <-- How to reference concrete My of passed generic Y
}
```

How can Z refer to My of given Y?

Comment: Where do you have a concrete `My`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a blackout.... it's just Y#My